# Receive "JSON::ParserError: 809: unexpected token at '<!DOCTYPE html>" when parsing response.body in specs

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, rspec

So, I lost far too much time trying to solve this. I would like to have parsed json response in my rspec request specs and for this I have created:

```
# support/helper_methods.rb

module HelperMethods
  
  def json_response
    JSON.parse(response.body)
  end

end
```

```
# rails_helper.rb

RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.include HelperMethods
end
```

and would like to use it in simple request spec:

```
# requests/post_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Posts', type: :request do
  describe 'GET /posts' do
    let(:post) { create(:post) }

    before { post }

    it 'returns status 200' do
      get '/posts'

      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end

    it 'renders posts' do
      get '/posts'

      expect(json_response).to include('Some title')
    end
  end
end
```

However, the second example fails with a message:

```
# bundle exec rspec result

Failures:

  1) Posts GET /posts renders posts
     Failure/Error: JSON.parse(response.body)
     
     JSON::ParserError:
       809: unexpected token at '<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
         <head>
           <title>Blog</title>
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
           
           
     
           <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-04c3ae28f07e1bf734223bf526d0cdd296440ef53bcb3f80b9f093c6bf02f747.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
           <script src="/packs-test/js/application-dd998cb6b794ecb7e8af.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
         </head>
     
         <body>
           <p id="notice"></p>
     
       <h1>Posts</h1>
     
       <table>
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th colspan="3"></th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
     
         <tbody>
     
             <tr>
               <td><a href="/posts/56">Some title</a></td>
               <td><a href="/posts/56/edit">Edit</a></td>
               <td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/posts/56">Destroy</a></td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
     
       <br>
     
       <a href="/posts/new">New Post</a>
     
         </body>
       </html>
       '
     # ./spec/support/helper_methods.rb:8:in `json_response'
     # ./spec/requests/posts_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 49.49 seconds (files took 0.46187 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/posts_spec.rb:17 # Posts GET /posts renders posts
```

I tried to see if this is some doctype problem, however skipping it gives just the same error, but with html tag this time. I believe this is something very much trivial, I can't see anything wrong tho.

I would really appreciate some help with this one.

Comment: HTML Is not JSON -- you cannot parse an HTML dom into JSON.

Comment: ah, you are completely right.. i forgot that my previous projects from where i have blindly copied it, were api-only. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turned out it was mistake on my side. As dbugger mentioned in a comment, you can't parse html files to json.